# How to calculate days between when last condition was met?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

current df:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("2020-01-12","d1",0),
    ("2020-01-12","d2",0),
    ("2020-01-13","d3",0),
    ("2020-01-14","d4",1), 
    ("2020-01-15","d5",0),
    ("2020-01-15","d6",0),
    ("2020-01-16","d7",0),
    ("2020-01-17","d8",0),
    ("2020-01-18","d9",1),
    ("2020-01-19","d10",0),
    ("2020-01-20","d11",0),], 
    ['date', 'device', 'condition'])

df.show()

+----------+------+---------+
|      date|device|condition|
+----------+------+---------+
|2020-01-12|    d1|        0|
|2020-01-12|    d2|        0|
|2020-01-13|    d3|        0|
|2020-01-14|    d4|        1|
|2020-01-15|    d5|        0|
|2020-01-15|    d6|        0|
|2020-01-16|    d7|        0|
|2020-01-17|    d8|        0|
|2020-01-18|    d9|        1|
|2020-01-19|   d10|        0|
|2020-01-20|   d11|        0|
+----------+------+---------+
```

desired output df:

```py
want_df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("2020-01-12","d1",0,0),
    ("2020-01-12","d2",0,0),
    ("2020-01-13","d3",0,1),
    ("2020-01-14","d4",1,2), 
    ("2020-01-15","d5",0,1),
    ("2020-01-15","d6",0,1),
    ("2020-01-16","d7",0,2),
    ("2020-01-17","d8",0,3),
    ("2020-01-18","d9",1,4),
    ("2020-01-19","d10",0,1),
    ("2020-01-20","d11",0,2),], 
    ['date', 'device', 'condition', 'life'])

want_df.show()

+----------+------+---------+----+
|      date|device|condition|life|
+----------+------+---------+----+
|2020-01-12|    d1|        0|   0|
|2020-01-12|    d2|        0|   0|
|2020-01-13|    d3|        0|   1|
|2020-01-14|    d4|        1|   2|
|2020-01-15|    d5|        0|   1|
|2020-01-15|    d6|        0|   1|
|2020-01-16|    d7|        0|   2|
|2020-01-17|    d8|        0|   3|
|2020-01-18|    d9|        1|   4|
|2020-01-19|   d10|        0|   1|
|2020-01-20|   d11|        0|   2|
+----------+------+---------+----+
```

Objective is to calculate the date difference (# of days) up to when the `condition=1` then the date difference resets to # of days starting from when the last condition was met.  `life` is the column trying to calculate. Any idea how to calculate this?  `Window` or `lag`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one type of questions which can be simplified by adding some temporary rows (we flag them and then remove them later)

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, lag, sum as fsum, first, datediff
```

(1) First, create a new dataframe df1 which replicates all Rows with condition == 1 but set their condition = 0 and flag = 1, union the resulting dataframe with the original dataframe(set flag = 0):

```
df1 = df.withColumn('flag', lit(0)).union(
    df.where('condition = 1').withColumn('condition', lit(0)).withColumn('flag', lit(1))
)
```

(2) Then, set up the following two Window Specs, use `w1` to help create a sub-group label `g` to group all consecutive rows until condition is switched from 1 to 0. add `flag` into orderBy() so that the newly added Rows sit right behind their corresponding row with condition = 1 and are grouped into the next group-label.

```
w1 = Window.partitionBy(lit(0)).orderBy('date', 'flag')
w2 = Window.partitionBy(lit(0), 'g').orderBy('date', 'flag')
```

**Note:** In case you have a huge dataframe, you might want to change `lit(0)` to some actual or calculated columns to avoid Spark moving all rows onto a single partition. **UPDATE:** Based on comments, the dataframe is a single time-series which can be loaded onto a single partition, thus using `lit(0)` should be enough.

(3) use lag and sum function over `w1` to find the sub-group label 'g' and then calculate the first_date in the same group use WindowSpec `w2`. this date is used to calculate the column 'life':

```
df2 = df1.withColumn('g', fsum((lag('condition').over(w1) == 1).astype('int')).over(w1)) \
    .withColumn('first_date', first('date').over(w2)) \
    .withColumn('life', datediff('date','first_date'))
df2.show()
+----------+------+---------+----+---+----------+----+
|      date|device|condition|flag|  g|first_date|life|
+----------+------+---------+----+---+----------+----+
|2020-01-12|    d1|        0|   0|  0|2020-01-12|   0|
|2020-01-12|    d2|        0|   0|  0|2020-01-12|   0|
|2020-01-13|    d3|        0|   0|  0|2020-01-12|   1|
|2020-01-14|    d4|        1|   0|  0|2020-01-12|   2|
|2020-01-14|    d4|        0|   1|  1|2020-01-14|   0|
|2020-01-15|    d5|        0|   0|  1|2020-01-14|   1|
|2020-01-15|    d6|        0|   0|  1|2020-01-14|   1|
|2020-01-16|    d7|        0|   0|  1|2020-01-14|   2|
|2020-01-17|    d8|        0|   0|  1|2020-01-14|   3|
|2020-01-18|    d9|        1|   0|  1|2020-01-14|   4|
|2020-01-18|    d9|        0|   1|  2|2020-01-18|   0|
|2020-01-19|   d10|        0|   0|  2|2020-01-18|   1|
|2020-01-20|   d11|        0|   0|  2|2020-01-18|   2|
+----------+------+---------+----+---+----------+----+
```

(4) drop temporary rows and columns to get the final dataframe:

```
df_new = df2.filter('flag = 0').drop('first_date', 'g', 'flag')
df_new.show()
+----------+------+---------+----+
|      date|device|condition|life|
+----------+------+---------+----+
|2020-01-12|    d1|        0|   0|
|2020-01-12|    d2|        0|   0|
|2020-01-13|    d3|        0|   1|
|2020-01-14|    d4|        1|   2|
|2020-01-15|    d5|        0|   1|
|2020-01-15|    d6|        0|   1|
|2020-01-16|    d7|        0|   2|
|2020-01-17|    d8|        0|   3|
|2020-01-18|    d9|        1|   4|
|2020-01-19|   d10|        0|   1|
|2020-01-20|   d11|        0|   2|
+----------+------+---------+----+
```

Comment: thanks so much!  what kind of column are you suggesting for your *note*?

Comment: any columns that can be used to split rows so that the calculations of `life` inside any split are independent from any other splits. On the other hand, if your data can not be split (for example, a single time-series), then either you can load your data onto a single partition using the current solution or partition by F.spark_partition_id() by which we will need to fix the first group on each partition based on the last Row from the previous partition(this will be another challenging to handle).

Comment: in fact, for a single time-series, I'd partition rows by `year` or `quarter` etc from `date` field instead of `spark_partition_id` and then fix the boundary on each partition (i.e. the first group `g = 0` on each partition)

Comment: ok thanks, yes - it is a single time series column, i can create the year and month column however it will not contain unique values hence not solving the single partition problem.  the dataset is rather small after aggregating by device so i should be ok.  your advice is very helpful!

Comment: if your dataset can be loaded into a single partition, then using lit(0) should be fine, using `year-month` only when your data can not be loaded onto one partition, in such case you don't want this to be unique:)

Comment: ok but when i partition by year and month the logic calculates incorrect ```life``` ... would adding a ```rangeBetween``` in the ```window``` fix this?

Comment: @thePurplePython, what I mean in my previous comments are if your data can be loaded onto one partition, then just use `partitionBy(lit(0))` as shown in the post, this is enough. However if your data are huge and can not be processed on a single partition, only in such case, you can partition by `year-month`, but will have to fix some rows on each partition with the calculated `g == 0` or `g is NULL`, this is expected. no need to adjust rangeBetween.

Answer (score 1):

I try to provide from different way, which more close to standard sql dialect, but still using pyspark syntax and concern to performance impact.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, lit, lag, min, max, datediff
```

Select date range that condition equal to 1,
then combining with max date value using union function.

```
w = Window.partitionBy('date')

dateRange = df.select(df.date).where(df.condition == 1)\
    .union(df.select(max(df.date))).distinct()\
    .orderBy('date')\
    .withColumn('lastDate', lag(col('date').over(w))\
    .select(when(col('lastDate').isNull(), lit('1970-01-01')).otherwise(col('lastDate')).alias('lastDate'), col('date').alias('toDate'))
```

Select date range and first minimum date by joining df with date range,
then make a grouping and calculating the minimum date value.

```
dateRange1st = df.join(dateRange, df.date > dateRange.lastDate & df.date <= dateRange.toDate, 'inner').groupBy(dateRange.lastDate, dateRange.toDate).agg(min(df.date).alias('frDate'))
```

Select the result by joining date range (1st) into df,
for help date filtering and find out the different.

```
result = df.join(dateRange1st, df.date.between(dateRange1st.frDate, dateRange1st.toDate), 'inner')\
    .select(df.date, df.device, df.condition)\
    .withColumn('life', datediff(df.date - dataRange1st.frDate))\
    .orderBy(df.date)

result.show()
```

Hope this helps!