# PySpark: How to calculate days between when last condition was met (positive vs negative)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Current DF (filter by a single userId, flag is 1 when the loss is > 0, -1 when is <=0):

```py
display(df):
+------+----------+---------+----+
|  user|Date      |RealLoss |flag|
+------+----------+---------+----+
|100364|2019-02-01|    -16.5|   1|
|100364|2019-02-02|     73.5|  -1|
|100364|2019-02-03|       31|  -1|
|100364|2019-02-09|     -5.2|   1|
|100364|2019-02-10|    -34.5|   1|
|100364|2019-02-13|     -8.1|   1|
|100364|2019-02-18|     5.68|  -1|
|100364|2019-02-19|     5.76|  -1|
|100364|2019-02-20|     9.12|  -1|
|100364|2019-02-26|      9.4|  -1|
|100364|2019-02-27|    -30.6|   1|
+----------+------+---------+----+
```

the desidered outcome df should show the number of days since lastwin ('RecencyLastWin') and since lastloss ('RecencyLastLoss')

```py
display(df):
+------+----------+---------+----+--------------+---------------+
|  user|Date      |RealLoss |flag|RecencyLastWin|RecencyLastLoss|
+------+----------+---------+----+--------------+---------------+
|100364|2019-02-01|    -16.5|   1|          null|           null|
|100364|2019-02-02|     73.5|  -1|             1|           null|
|100364|2019-02-03|       31|  -1|             2|              1|     
|100364|2019-02-09|     -5.2|   1|             8|              6|
|100364|2019-02-10|    -34.5|   1|             1|              7|
|100364|2019-02-13|     -8.1|   1|             1|             10|
|100364|2019-02-18|     5.68|  -1|             5|             15|         
|100364|2019-02-19|     5.76|  -1|             6|              1|
|100364|2019-02-20|     9.12|  -1|             7|              1|
|100364|2019-02-26|      9.4|  -1|            13|              6|
|100364|2019-02-27|    -30.6|   1|            14|              1|
+----------+------+---------+----+--------------+---------------+
```

My approach was the following:

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.partitionBy("userId", 'PlayerSiteCode').orderBy("EventDate")

last_positive = check.filter('flag = "1"').withColumn('last_positive_day' , F.lag('EventDate').over(w))
last_negative = check.filter('flag = "-1"').withColumn('last_negative_day' , F.lag('EventDate').over(w))

finalcheck = check.join(last_positive.select('userId', 'PlayerSiteCode', 'EventDate', 'last_positive_day'), ['userId', 'PlayerSiteCode', 'EventDate'], how = 'left')\
                  .join(last_negative.select('userId', 'PlayerSiteCode', 'EventDate', 'last_negative_day'), ['userId', 'PlayerSiteCode', 'EventDate'], how = 'left')\
                  .withColumn('previous_date_played'         , F.lag('EventDate').over(w))\
                  .withColumn('last_positive_day_count', F.datediff(F.col('EventDate'), F.col('last_positive_day')))\
                  .withColumn('last_negative_day_count', F.datediff(F.col('EventDate'), F.col('last_negative_day')))
```

then I tried to add (multiple attempts..) but failed to 'perfectly' return what I want.

```
finalcheck = finalcheck.withColumn('previous_last_pos'           , F.last('last_positive_day_count', True).over(w2))\
                        .withColumn('previous_last_neg'           , F.last('last_negative_day_count', True).over(w2))\
                        .withColumn('previous_last_pos_date'      , F.last('last_positive_day', True).over(w2))\
                        .withColumn('previous_last_neg_date'      , F.last('last_negative_day', True).over(w2))\
                        .withColumn('recency_last_positive'       , F.datediff(F.col('EventDate'), F.col('previous_last_pos_date')))\
                        .withColumn('day_since_last_negative_v1'  , F.datediff(F.col('EventDate'), F.col('previous_last_neg_date')))\
                        .withColumn('days_off'                    , F.datediff(F.col('EventDate'), F.col('previous_date_played')))\
                        .withColumn('recency_last_negative'       , F.when((F.col('day_since_last_negative_v1').isNull()), F.col('days_off')).otherwise(F.col('day_since_last_negative_v1')))\
                        .withColumn('recency_last_negative_v2'    , F.when((F.col('last_negative_day').isNull()), F.col('days_off')).otherwise(F.col('day_since_last_negative_v1')))\
                        .withColumn('recency_last_positive_v2'    , F.when((F.col('last_positive_day').isNull()), F.col('days_off')).otherwise(F.col('recency_last_positive')))
```

Any suggestion/tips?
(I found a similar question but didn't figured out how to apply in my specific case):
[How to calculate days between when last condition was met?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59709531/how-to-calculate-days-between-when-last-condition-was-met)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my try.

There are two parts to calculate this. The first one is that when the wins and losses keep going, then the difference of dates should be summed. To achieve this, I have marked the consecutive losses and wins as 1, and split them into the partition groups by cumulative summing until the current row of the marker. Then, I can calculate the cumulative days from the last loss or win after the consecutive losses and wins the end.

The second one is that when the wins and losses changed, simply get the date difference from the last match and this match. It can be easily obtained by the date difference of current and previous one.

Finally, merge those results in a column.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lag, col, sum
from pyspark.sql import Window

w1 = Window.orderBy('Date')
w2 = Window.partitionBy('groupLossCheck').orderBy('Date')
w3 = Window.partitionBy('groupWinCheck').orderBy('Date')

df2 = df.withColumn('lastFlag', lag('flag', 1).over(w1)) \
  .withColumn('lastDate', lag('Date', 1).over(w1)) \
  .withColumn('dateDiff', expr('datediff(Date, lastDate)')) \
  .withColumn('consecutiveLoss', expr('if(flag =  1 or lastFlag =  1, 0, 1)')) \
  .withColumn('consecutiveWin' , expr('if(flag = -1 or lastFlag = -1, 0, 1)')) \
  .withColumn('groupLossCheck', sum('consecutiveLoss').over(w1)) \
  .withColumn('groupWinCheck' , sum('consecutiveWin' ).over(w1)) \
  .withColumn('daysLastLoss', sum(when((col('consecutiveLoss') == 0) & (col('groupLossCheck') != 0), col('dateDiff'))).over(w2)) \
  .withColumn('daysLastwin' , sum(when((col('consecutiveWin' ) == 0) & (col('groupWinCheck' ) != 0), col('dateDiff'))).over(w3)) \
  .withColumn('lastLoss', expr('if(lastFlag = -1, datediff, null)')) \
  .withColumn('lastWin' , expr('if(lastFlag =  1, dateDiff, null)')) \
  .withColumn('RecencyLastLoss', coalesce('lastLoss', 'daysLastLoss')) \
  .withColumn('RecencyLastWin',  coalesce('lastWin' , 'daysLastwin' )) \
  .orderBy('Date')

df2.show(11, False)

+------+----------+--------+----+--------+----------+--------+---------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+------------+-----------+--------+-------+---------------+--------------+
|user  |Date      |RealLoss|flag|lastFlag|lastDate  |dateDiff|consecutiveLoss|consecutiveWin|groupLossCheck|groupWinCheck|daysLastLoss|daysLastwin|lastLoss|lastWin|RecencyLastLoss|RecencyLastWin|
+------+----------+--------+----+--------+----------+--------+---------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+------------+-----------+--------+-------+---------------+--------------+
|100364|2019-02-01|-16.5   |1   |null    |null      |null    |0              |1             |0             |1            |null        |null       |null    |null   |null           |null          |
|100364|2019-02-02|73.5    |-1  |1       |2019-02-01|1       |0              |0             |0             |1            |null        |1          |null    |1      |null           |1             |
|100364|2019-02-03|31.0    |-1  |-1      |2019-02-02|1       |1              |0             |1             |1            |null        |2          |1       |null   |1              |2             |
|100364|2019-02-09|-5.2    |1   |-1      |2019-02-03|6       |0              |0             |1             |1            |6           |8          |6       |null   |6              |8             |
|100364|2019-02-10|-34.5   |1   |1       |2019-02-09|1       |0              |1             |1             |2            |7           |null       |null    |1      |7              |1             |
|100364|2019-02-13|-8.1    |1   |1       |2019-02-10|3       |0              |1             |1             |3            |10          |null       |null    |3      |10             |3             |
|100364|2019-02-18|5.68    |-1  |1       |2019-02-13|5       |0              |0             |1             |3            |15          |5          |null    |5      |15             |5             |
|100364|2019-02-19|5.76    |-1  |-1      |2019-02-18|1       |1              |0             |2             |3            |null        |6          |1       |null   |1              |6             |
|100364|2019-02-20|9.12    |-1  |-1      |2019-02-19|1       |1              |0             |3             |3            |null        |7          |1       |null   |1              |7             |
|100364|2019-02-26|9.4     |-1  |-1      |2019-02-20|6       |1              |0             |4             |3            |null        |13         |6       |null   |6              |13            |
|100364|2019-02-27|-30.6   |1   |-1      |2019-02-26|1       |0              |0             |4             |3            |1           |14         |1       |null   |1              |14            |
+------+----------+--------+----+--------+----------+--------+---------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+------------+-----------+--------+-------+---------------+--------------+

df2.select(*df.columns, 'RecencyLastLoss', 'RecencyLastWin').show(11, False)

+------+----------+--------+----+---------------+--------------+
|user  |Date      |RealLoss|flag|RecencyLastLoss|RecencyLastWin|
+------+----------+--------+----+---------------+--------------+
|100364|2019-02-01|-16.5   |1   |null           |null          |
|100364|2019-02-02|73.5    |-1  |null           |1             |
|100364|2019-02-03|31.0    |-1  |1              |2             |
|100364|2019-02-09|-5.2    |1   |6              |8             |
|100364|2019-02-10|-34.5   |1   |7              |1             |
|100364|2019-02-13|-8.1    |1   |10             |3             |
|100364|2019-02-18|5.68    |-1  |15             |5             |
|100364|2019-02-19|5.76    |-1  |1              |6             |
|100364|2019-02-20|9.12    |-1  |1              |7             |
|100364|2019-02-26|9.4     |-1  |6              |13            |
|100364|2019-02-27|-30.6   |1   |1              |14            |
+------+----------+--------+----+---------------+--------------+
```